# Checkboxes disabled and enabled

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am looking to make a (by default) disabled check box enabled only if and when another check box is checked. This allows me to check the newly enabled check box. The catch is on form submission the check box should stay enabled if the other is checked.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I am enabled and must be clicked<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" name="vehicle" value="Car" disabled>I am waiting to be enabled
```

I am looking to do with jquery, I don't have any jquery code to show cause I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the change function to see when box was checked, and logic from there to enable and disable.

```
$("#checkbox1").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#checkbox2").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else {
        $("#checkbox2").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your `if` might as well be `if (this.checked)` (it'll be `true` if it's checked, and `false` if not), no need for jQuery's `is()`, it's a Boolean all by itself, and certainly no need to reselect the current element-node.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the second checkbox to become disabled after the first checkbox is unchecked, use this:

```
$('#checkbox1').click(function () {
    $('#checkbox2').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ANZ7x/)**

otherwise just use this:

```
$('#checkbox1').click(function () {
    $('#checkbox2').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ANZ7x/1/)**

Comment: what about after form submission? will the disabled check box that is now enabled, stay enabled?

Comment: How are you submitting the form? Normally or via AJAX?

Comment: normal submission, also the issue with number 2 in js fiddle is that once checkbox1 is clicked no matter if checkbox one is unclicked or not you cal always click on checkbox 2..

Comment: If you're submitting the form normally then the page will reload and none of the setting will persist unless you use cookies, sessions, etc to store them.